# Program that count all characters appearing consecutively

Tags: arrays, count, character

Problem: Character count
INPUT: A word and count all characters appearing consecutively.
OUTPUT: The number of characters appearing consecutively and the letters
Sample Run:
Enter string: Mississippi
3
ssp

Enter string: Committee
3
mte

Enter string: mmmmrrnzzz
4
mmrz

Im a first year college student taking Bachelor of Science in Computer Science. Im hoping you can help me for this problem Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may want to post some code for better help. People here are really picky about helping with homework. They want to see that you have made a valid effort at completing this before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem, but probably the best way for a first year student is to use a loop to solve it.

I don't want to give to many details as that defeats the purpose of the exercise, but the basic process might look something like this:

Treat the string as an array of characters. So the word committee is really `c o m m i t t e e`. Create a variable to hold the `max repeat count`, `current repeat count` and `repeat letters`. Also create a variable for the `current letter` and initialize it to "".

```
for each letter in the input string
  does this letter match the value in current_letter?
  if yes
    increment the current_repeat_count variable
    append the current_letter to the repeat_letters array
    if current_repeat_count > max_repeat_count
       max_repeat_count = current_repeat_count
  else
    current_letter = the letter you just tested
    current_repeat_count = 0
```

I hope that gets you started.